# fread how to Count total from Counter text

Tags: counter, hit

hey i have a counter text here and i need to know how to calculate the total this is my information

$filename = "data.txt";
$handle   = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$expode   = explode("\n",$contents);

/**
output 
1024
1024
1024
1024
1024
1024
1024
1024
1024
1024
1024
1024
1024
*/
I i need to calculate the total by exploding "\n" so i will output 12288 need to understand how to do this i have done this

foreach ($expode as $v) 
{ 
    $total  = $total + $v;

```
echo $total;
```

} 
i did not get good results with this

Comment: What was your result? Are they always 1024? you could do a count( explode( "\n", $contents ) ) * 1024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    /**
     * @author Saxtor Inc
     * @copyright 2010
     */

    function TotalBytes($definefilename)
    {  
         $isfile     = is_file($definefilename); //define the file name

            if ($isfile == 1) //if the file is true
         {
            $handle   = fopen($definefilename, "r"); //open the file check the information
            $contents = fread($handle, filesize($definefilename)); //define the filesize
            $expode   = explode("\n", $contents); //explode the "\n char"
            $count    = count($expode, COUNT_RECURSIVE); //count how much total
            while ($i <= $count) //count total values

            {
                $totalcount = $totalcount + $expode[$i] . "\n"; //count total values; :D
                $i++;
            }
            return $totalcount; //return total aye it works

        }
        else
        {
            return "Not Found";
        }
    }
    echo TotalBytes('data.txt');

?>
```